# Switching career from firmware engineer to hardware engineer. Is it possible?

Tags: career-switch

I graduated as an Electronic Engineer (mostly digital) last year, and am passionate about electronics for a long time. Since most hardware work with firmwares today, I found my passion in microcontroller programming.

After graduation, I found a job as a low level firmware developer. I have this job for almost a year now.

But I have a fear that if I work in this field longer, it may be increasingly difficult to change career, even if I would be willing to start again as a trainee in the new field.

I am thinking more about this as I want to work on hardware designing (specifically, I am referring to analog/digital/power systems). But I don't know if I am rushing, or even if this is a good idea.

**PS**: Hardware design does not imply working as an IC developer, but rather PCB / discrete solutions design.

(Thanks for your opinions.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you cubby-holed yourself as a firmware engineer, you are doing something wrong. Firmware works hand-in-hand with hardware. To write **good** firmware, you need to know the "in"s and "out"s of your hardware really well. So well that, you might have as well designed it.

If you look at it from this angle, the difference between h/w engineer and f/w engineer is already very blurry in my opinion. But if your desire is to go play with PCBs, soldering, putting discrete components together to make a circuit board, you just need to find a position which will give you this opportunity.

Having said this, as an EE with both BS and MS degrees myself, let me clue you in on something that you might be overlooking: The days of building harware with your bare hands is basically over. In the past, when I was a fresh grad out of faculty of electrical engineering, we had a chance to go to the electronics parts store, buy an 8086 CPU, some RAM chips and get a wiring board and put together a low grade computer system which actually worked. Now, go open the guts of any electronic device if you will. All you see is two or three surface mounted components, doing everything under the sun. Unless you are the FPGA and/or ASIC designer, under the name of hardware design, you are basically doing nothing as a hardware engineer but rearranging what someone else had developed. And when you talk of chip design, you are again talking about a very low level firmware design, unless you are really into silicon dicing and fabrication process engineering.

Yes, there still are power systems, which use discrete components to build, but everything going low power nowadays, the glory days of power systems engineering is not too long in my opinion.

So, in short, you can do what you want, but your area of work is shrinking with every passing day. Leaving your current careerpath and going h/w engineering route, is a little risky for job security, if you ask me.

My 2 cents.

Comment: +1 - pure hardware design is becoming more & more of a niche, and even then its often a case of tweaking an existing design from a handful of app-notes.

Comment: Good answer, I have met many engineers who wouldn't be able to design/build a circuit board that actually works. They don't need to anymore.

Comment: @brhans I definitely agree with you, I have designed a lot of stuff for polytechic and myself, maybe I know what you mean.

To Mel, thank for the advice! But let me specify: I talk about hw design (using CAD tools), not building it. That's true, outside IC design is more like assembling a puzzle, but consider that power systems (power LED, as example) are out there. To be precise, IC design is not out of my target in these considerations, and also IC analog design exist even though it is not very my field.

Comment: I remember when at university we designed a simple uP (not very a uP, but very similar with help of some tools) in order to be used using a certain rudimental assembly language: the digital IC design ends when the low level programming starts, and viceversa. Fascinating.

Comment: The example of designing a power LED you mentioned. Well, it is not h/w engineering in my opinion but rather materials engineering. an LED is a p-n junction diode, which emits light when proper voltage applied. After that whatever you do in the name of design is to arrange these LEDs in a certain shape or form to suit a need. IC design is pretty much the same way. gazillion NAND gates squeezed into a silicon substrate. Designing the chip is basically jockeying the position of NPN transistors. Which if you ask me, is done better by software than manual effort, hence called f/w I rest my case :)

Comment: Designing an IC of course requires a software. This does not mean that is like putting transistors toghether, there is real high level knowledge in people who design ICs, as much a people who design the CAD to make them. The analogy is a compiler for a PC SW: programming in C does not mean that you are not able to program simply because you rely on another software. Neither who design the compiler or the CAD tool is capable of designing a complex OS or a full IC: each one (the CAD developer or tha CAD user) handle the complexity at different levels.

Comment: One more thing: designing a power LED system, is not so trivial when the design shall be made in the state of the art of technology or making it with consciousness. And, people who made the LED at PN junction level, is very likely that they do not have the knowledge of making it working properly as the HW/board designer would do. There is knowledge and a lot of math at "board level" too. I am not considering all the RF designer outside the IC level, but also them are in the same argument. This is an interesting discussion.

Comment: There is something I would like to add to this answer. After years of experience, I am an electronics (system) designer working with firmware people, making the electronics to make my algorithms work, both in HW and SW. The best FW engineers I worked with have CS background with electronics knowledge, but deep electronics knowledge is more and more kept with HW people. Basics must be known by all, but I'm talking about expertise here. So today seem you tend to pidgeon hole in software, if you start with Firmware. Opinions are welcome

Comment: @thexeno I, myself, am also an electrical & electronics engineer, who found himself in the IT trenches after 7 years of hardcore work in electronics manufacturing and testing, staright out of college and I tend to agree with you. Albeit, I can not say best firmware engineers come from CS or EE backgrounds.  The best people I worked with are extremely analytical people who are well versed in writing code and understanding what they are working with H/W wise. I personally abhor working with F/W engineers who write code in a high level language and compile/optimize. Assembly language rules the FW